# How can I create a SEO friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have my website name as www.example.com but the 'example' is not related to any of my keywords.
But my competitors have. Is there any solution for index page?
All others Page maintains the proper naming_standard but for index page it creates a problem.

Here's my .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.example.com$1 [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^/index.cfm$ http\://www.example.com [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^/main.cfm$ http\://www.example.com [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^/ww.example.com$ http\://www.example.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^ww.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.example.com$1 [NC,R=301,U]
```

Comment: Can you pls clarify what it is you're asking?

Comment: My domain name is not related to any of my keywords. Say my website name is www.shreyanshu.com but I supply products like cellphones and computer. There's nothing relation between URL and my keywords. And I noticed that URLs having keywords impact more than those who are not having.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.cfm / [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/main.cfm / [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first two rules stop people going to index.cfm and main.cfm directly and redirects them to the base URL.

The third condition and fourth rule check the domain is "www.example.com" and if it is anything else, e.g. without the www. or an alias, 301 redirects them to the same page on "www.example.com".